# Lagrangian of a block connected to a circular track

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

Could someone help me? I am having trouble with obtaining the same result in part b) for this problem: 
[image]
[image]

Using the Lagrange Equation with respect to $\theta$, I obtained $$\ddot{x}cos\theta+a\ddot{\theta}+\dot{\theta}\dot{x}sin\theta+gsin\theta = 0\qquad(1)$$
And since $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=0,$$ then $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}} $
is a constant of motion, given in the solution.  I am confused as to what my next step should be to obtain the given solution. Since Eq. 1 has the extra term $\dot{\theta}\dot{x}sin\theta$ I would assume that since $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}} $ is constant, then it can be solved for $\dot{x}$ and plugged into Eq. 1.
And then when solving the Lagrange equation with respect to $x$ I can use the obtained constant to complete that equation as well.  It seems that the extra term in Eq. 1 just disappears completely and their constant was determined to be $$ma\dot{\theta}^2sin\theta$$. Could someone give insight as to how this solution for part b) was obtained?

*This is a problem out of "Major American Universities Ph.D. Qualifying Questions and Solutions: Problems and Solutions on Mechanics"

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure your equation (1) is missing a term. The first term in $\frac{\mathrm{d}L}{\mathrm{d}\theta}$ should cancel the last term in $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \frac{\mathrm{d}l}{\mathrm{d}(\theta)'}.$

I am very sorry for not using math symbols, that is because I don't know how; and evidently the derivative in between {} are meant to be partials.

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! See https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation for information about notation.

Comment: We use MathJax for notation. A quick way to learn: find a post that shows what you want, and then edit it to see the code behind the notation.